# Can I define a Type variable for which Types representing subtypes of a specific class are the only valid values?

Tags: c#, types

### Background

I'm writing some components ([this kind of component](http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy/)) for a small personal game project. In this system, entities have various types of components which belong to various categories. For example, the *IController* category of components includes *KeyboardController* and *AiController*. An entity has a collection of components, and should only have one component from each category. All components inherit from *IComponent*.

Components have a *MetaType* property which should report a type they correspond to, in order to say: "Hey, please treat me as this type of component!" This property returns a *Type* object. The *AiController* returns *typeof(IController)*, telling the Entity to treat this as its controller. Other valid MetaTypes for it would be *typeof(AiController)* or *typeof(IComponent)*. It should not be able to return any arbitrary type, e.g. *typeof(int)* - just component types.

### My problem

Currently my components can report any arbitrary type for a MetaType. The *AIController* can actually return *typeof(int)*, for instance - that's a valid Type object, after all.

Can I constrain the *Type* values such that the only valid types would be the type of any class or interface for which *IComponent* is an ancestor? I imagine such a variable declaration might look like this:

```
Type<IComponent> component; // This can only store certain types
Type where Type : IComponent component; // This too
```

**I am specifically interested in whether this is possible** - not so much in alternate approaches (I am aware of several, and they include just allowing this behaviour, since I'm the only one working with this code.

Comment: The larger question is why you think this is necessary, rather than just implementing a tree of generic sub-types implementing IController?

Comment: That's clearly insufficient reason, as it is simply duplicating the control you already obtain from your generics. Think about it for 5 minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a `MetaType` object whose constructors or factory methods would take a generic type constrained against `IComponent` and provide access to the non-constrained `Type`. But since its constructors are constrained, you *should* be guaranteed to not get other non-IComponents.

```
public class MetaType
{
    public Type ComponentType { get; private set; }

    private MetaType(Type componentType)
    {
        this.ComponentType = componentType;
    }

    public static MetaType Create<T>() where T : IComponent
    {
        return new MetaType(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Your usage might look like:

```
MetaType validType = MetaType.Create<IComponent>(); //fine
MetaType validType = MetaType.Create<IController>(); //fine
MetaType validType = MetaType.Create<AIController>(); //fine

MetaType invalidType = MetaType.Create<int>(); //compiler error!
```

EDIT: I'm assuming that your `IController` interface inherits from `IComponent`, but if it doesn't, you can add factory overloads like `CreateController` and `CreateComponent` each one constrained against the unique interface.

Comment: You're correct in your assumption. Thanks, this is exactly what I was after - complete with compile time type protection.

Comment: Month after having upvoted this answer, and having re-adapted this pattern to a method in my utility library, I'm honestly still trying to find an example where it comes in help and where generics does not suffice on their own.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, unfortunately - whilst you can constrain type *parameters* in generics, type *variables* like your `MetaType` field can't be constrained. It's basically like trying to constrain an `int`: you can use exceptions to make sure it's never set to an invalid value but ultimately the variable itself could be anything of the right type.